# Can i save this mango?

Tags: diagnosis

Started from seed from store bought mango about 3 months ago. Quickly growed to this stage and then stuck. Seems to be getting worse last 2 weeks. No idea what is wrong. Temps was 20-30c during that period. [image]

Comment: Are you aware that a mango grown from seed will probably not produce edible fruit?

Comment: No, why is that ? Anyway, full size mango would probably take several years, so I wasn't really counting on that.

Comment: Mangoes are propagated from cuttings from other mango trees, which means they're clones. Mangoes grown from seed typically revert to wild-type fruit, which is extremely fibrous, instead of the juicy texture of the mangos we like to eat. Thousands of years ago, kings used to send gardeners to steal branches from their rivals' gardens.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save it, you might try using some fresh, new potting soil in a different,, clean pot, a smaller one more suited to the size of the seedling initially, and moving it into that instead. It looks like the pot you've used has old soil in it with other weeds and moss growing; the moss would suggest the soil has been pretty damp quite a lot of the time, as well as an indicator that the soil is compacted.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it was brand new potting soil. Did i water it too much ? I remember reading somewhere that mangos need a lot of water.

Comment: Well the other problem is the pot's too big  - little plants need little pots, then being moved on into bigger pots as they grow and get larger. All that unoccupied soil round your tiny seedling will inevitably be colonised by other weeds/plants,and your seedling will be sitting in wet soil because you  have to  water it to keep the seedling supplied - but all that soil remains wet for too long, there's nothing using up the excess water. If you can, move into a much smaller pot ...